# Why does isInsideSecureHardware's return value change across API levels on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-keystore, hsm

Below is the code that I'm running on my Android Emulator:

```java
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore"); // store the key in the Android KeyStore for security purposes
keyGen.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
        "key1",
        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
        .build()); // defaults to RSA 2048
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(keyPair.getPrivate().getAlgorithm(), "AndroidKeyStore");
KeyInfo keyInfo = factory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPrivate(), KeyInfo.class);
boolean secure = keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware();
System.out.println("Is the private key backed in hardware: " + secure);
```

---

These are the returns that I get across the different versions:
API Level 27: `true`
API Level 28: `false`
API Level 29: `false`

Why does `isInsideSecureHardware`'s return value change across API levels? I would think that this would rely entirely on the hardware and not the API level that's running on the phone.

Comment: @PedroRomão Unfortunately I did not